# rails 3 domain for mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, mailer

in my config/application.rb file I have a line:

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
```

How can I configure the host attribute for default url options automaticaly from the domain, where my Rails app is hosted ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be explicitly specified somewhere because how else would rails know what the domain is?.. A request through the browser (or curl, or whatever) will have a host which rails knows about, but if you load up rails console, what would the domain be?

If you're using something like capistrano, you could write a task to create an initializer which sets the mailer url depending on the host(s) you've set in your deploy recipe.

Comment: Ok, but assuming, the request is coming trough http. Where I can setup the host before I send the email ?